# My app is not in the Share-Via list

Tags: android

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imagesharer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.imagesharer.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.imagesharer.ShareActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.imagesharer.ImageCaptureActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I select an image from the gallery and tap on share, my app is not present in the list of apps displayed.

Since I believe every thing is proper. I tried cleaning the project, restarting the device .. but still the same.

What am I missing.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the exported="false"?

"Whether or not the activity can be launched by components of other applications — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. If "false", the activity can be launched only by components of the same application or applications with the same user ID."

Comment: I have changed it to **true**. `android:exported="true"` But still I cannot see my app in the share-via list.

Comment: Doh i mixed it up. By doing the intent filter route, your app will show up in the app chooser if an app sent a SEND intent. What you are referring to is the Easy Share Action which is different.

Comment: Yeah. Still the same.